# Can you update in safe mode?

Tags: software-update

I am running Mac 10.6.2 and I want to update to 10.6.8. I have downloaded the update dmg already but want to install in safe boot and not normal. I am aware that many kexts are not loaded except from the core ones but will this stop the installer from installing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked fine. In fact I updated to 10.10 successfully in safe boot.